# I can't remember the name of a character in Marvel Comics (anti-hero)

Tags: marvel, character-identification

He is related to the X-Men comics in some way, and he wears mostly white. He has a mask that covers everything except for his eyes and the space between them and has telepathy. I think he also carries two guns.

Comment: Lorendiac is probably right, but if not, could it be Deadpool in his white suit (https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/e2/6f/d1/e26fd128ed4cbee47414b9a93c514d10.jpg)?

He's got two guns, and his eyes are glowing red in this costume (which could make someone unfamiliar with the character believe that they're uncovered), and he frequently talks to himself with several different styles of text boxes, which could be misread as telepathy if someone only saw a few pages out of context.

Answer (score 12):

Probably you are thinking of **Fantomex**, who was introduced during Grant Morrison's run as an X-Men writer. (Which I happened to be buying at the time.) The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantomex) on Fantomex says that he debuted in *New X-Men #128*, published in 2002.

[image: Fantomex on the cover of New X-Men]

- Wears a mostly-white outfit?
  Check!
- A mask that covers most of his head, but leaves the bit around his eyes uncovered?
  Check!
- Carries handguns?
  Check!
- Telepathy?
  Well, he can generate powerful illusions, and he is essentially immune to other people's telepathy, but he doesn't seem to be a true-blue telepath himself. (I suspect your memory blurred a few details. Or perhaps you have read a comic book story written by somebody who thought Fantomex did, in fact, have some telepathy in his bag of tricks?)